Why are library() calls hitting my R memory limit?
I'm working on a laravel app that connects to a R server via Rserve (using  ctuberlin/rserve). The app is in a docker container and the R process is running on a separate container. Link to GitHub here.
The app allows us to make tasks and exercises in R that are corrected automatically. We have to limit resources for each user session so that faulty student code doesn't take out the whole docker container.
We are using unix::rlimit_as(1e9) as a memory limit.
Problem is, whenever the exercise requires some library, the library() call hits an error.
Example of errors:
r_1      | Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘png’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
r_1      |  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/site-library/png/libs/png.so':
r_1      |   /usr/lib/R/site-library/png/libs/png.so: failed to map segment from shared object

Or testing manually inside the container (with docker exec):
> unix::rlimit_as(1e9)
$cur
[1] 1e+09

$max
[1] Inf

> library(RMySQL)
Loading required package: DBI
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DBI’:
 memory exhausted
Error: package ‘DBI’ could not be loaded

Removing the rlimit call or moving it to after the library call avoids this error.
I don't understand why this is happening, since if I run the exact same commands on my local system, it works fine. It could be an issue with the container configuration? I'm at a loss as to how to troubleshoot this.
Links to my R container Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml.
